# Ordenar Datagridview según celdas con datos

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Compañeros. Tengo un datagridview que posee los campos USUARIO, LECTURA, OBSERVACIÓN, SECTOR. El campo usuario y sector siempre están llenos pero los campos lectura y observación pueden estar vacíos, o puede haber una fila con un usuario que solo tenga lectura, o que solo tenga observación. También hay veces en que ambos campos están llenos y vacíos.

Para ordenar por sector uso creo un dataset y luego uso la propiedad .sort de este modo

```
dtView.Sort = "SECTOR ASC, LECTURA DESC, OBSERVACION DESC"
```

Lo que me tiene complicado es que no encuentro el modo de que una vez estén los usuarios ordenados por sector se muestren primero todos los que tienen los campos LECTURA y OBSERVACION llenos primero y de ahí hacia abajo se muestren ordenados por lectura y observacion

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que necesito:

Pasar de esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos los saco de un excel que importo al datagridview así que la idea es hacer esto directamente en el datagridview en lugar de utilizar filtros en el excel

Comment: Ya intentaste traer dicha información ordenada de esa manera, directamente de base de datos ?

Comment: Hola, compañero. Por desgracia es imposible ya que esa tabla se genera tras procesar dos excel diferentes y los datos quedan en ese datagridview. No hay base de datos de por medio